# sub sub domain being added with my domain

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, dns, certificate

Recently I have seen that one of my client domain is being prefixed with subdomain such as `www.ww / wwww.www / www.webmail / www.ns2` etc.

The changes we have made is added ssl certificate for security i.e. from `http://www.<domain.com>` to `https://www.<domain.com>`

I have no clues from where these links are being created. Even Google indexes them.

The biggest problem I am facing is when someone clicks on these links then a certificate warning is shown, which says it is not safe to open this page.

I have made and performed `.htaccess` redirection for the same, but still the warning is there.

One post on Stack Overflow suggested that it is to be done on Apache level and server is required to be restarted.

Comment: It is impossible to solve the certificate issue by means of rewrite rules, since it is the first request that is answered with a certificate that is not issued for the requested host name. Nothing you can do, except including all those host names into your certificate.

Comment: We obviously cannot help you with the issue of those host names, since you have absolutely no information about your setup.

Comment: If you do not want these sub-sub domains, the problem is with your DNS configuration. Speak to your DNS provider, or look at your DNS configuration panel.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we would need access to the poster's DNS configuration in order to assist.

Comment: Hello, Many thanks for all responses. I think as you say, it might be due to some mis-configuration in DNS. Following are the DNS entries I have seen on parallel plesk 12 for my domain. For the security reasons, I have removed domain and ip addresses

Comment: PTR domain.com.
<ip address> / 24              PTR domain.com.
ftp.domain.com.                CNAME domain.com.
ipv4.domain.com.             A         <ip address>
ipv6.domain.com.            AAAA 2607:<ip address v6>
mail.domain.com.            A         <ip address>
mail.domain.com.            AAAA 2607:<ip address v6>
ns.domain.com.              A          <ip address>
ns.domain.com.              AAAA 2607:<ip address v6>
domain.com.                   NS         ns.domain.com.
domain.com.                   A         <ip address>

Comment: domain.com.                   AAAA 2607:<ip address v6>
domain.com.                   MX (10) mail.domain.com.
domain.com.                   TXT         v=spf1 +a +mx -all                   +a:u17984470.onlinehome-server.com
webmail.domain.com.       A         <ip address>
webmail.domain.com.       AAAA 2607:<ip address v6>
www.domain.com.            CNAME domain.com.